# Replacing inner text with javascript and regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to do a modify a text which contain some special tags. I believe it should be possible by a single regular expression, but am stuck...

What I want to do is easier to explain by an example:

If I have this text:

> {Lorem Ipsum} is simply {dummy text} of
>   the printing and typesetting industry.

I want as a result this:

```
<span>Lorem Ipsum</span> is <span>simply dummy</span> text of the printing and typesetting industry.
```

I a `}` is encountered with no previous matching `{` then it should be ignored.

I know I can match all inner texts with this `\{(.*?)\}` but am lost on how to proceed, any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close.

```
text = text.replace(/{(.*?)}/g, '<span>$1</span>')
```

should do the trick. The `g` modifier makes `replace` to replace every occurrence of the pattern and `$1` refers to the content of the first capture group.

Btw. escaping the `{}` is not necessary here as `{(.*?)}` is not a special construct. It still might be better to escape them for clarity.

More about regular expression in JavaScript in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to match `\{([^{}]*)\}`. This ensures that only innermost pairs of braces are matched; unbalanced matches are impossible this way.

```
result = subject.replace(/\{([^{}]*)\}/g, "<span>$1</span>");
```

However, this will have to be applied several times if nested braces are possible. And it doesn't check whether those braces occur in comments, quotes etc., of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '{Lorem Ipsum} is simply {dummy text} of the printing and typesetting industry.';
var spanStr = str.replace(/{(.*?)}/g, '<span>$1</span>');
```